# Bitbucket Pipelines - Cannot find symbol: class UniversalDetector

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines

I tried to import `juniversalcharset` package on `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.juniversalchardet</groupId>
    <artifactId>juniversalchardet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

```
image: maven:3.3.3

pipelines:
    default:
        - step:
            caches:
                - maven
            script:
                - mvn clean install -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true
```

It downloads and builds correctly on my local machine, but on pipelines it displays the following error:

```
[ERROR] /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/src/main/java/package/location/GuessedEncoding.java:[18,15] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class UniversalDetector
```

My guess is that it cannot find the maven artifact when building on pipelines. Is there something wrong with my pipeline configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I forgot to commit and push `pom.xml` which is why pipelines failed to find the new packages.